# Filter Repeater through jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a table (asp:Repeater), that I want to filter based on the data in a particular column. The column in question contains the user that created the quote (row) and I want a user to only see their rows when the page loads. I plan on doing this by having a btn-group at the top that has Mine and All as options so I can toggle between the two modes.

"All" should be easy enough to figure out once I get the first one, but I'm not real familiar with jQuery and I can't find a great way to do this. All I see is filtering by classes.

<s>any advice/direction would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!</s>
Don't give me advice/direction. I definitely don't want that.

EDIT: here's the code to make *some* people happy...

```
function pageLoad(sender,args)
    {
        var rows = $('table#quotes tr').rows;

        $('input[type=submit]#myQuotes').click(function () {
            if (!$('#myQuotes').hasClass('active'))
            {
                //filter Repeater based on Owner Column
                $('#myQuotes').toggleClass('active');
                $('#allQuotes').toggleClass('active');
            }
        });
        $('input[type=submit]#allQuotes').click(function () {
            if (!$('#allQuotes').hasClass('active')) {
                $('#allQuotes').toggleClass('active');
                $('#myQuotes').toggleClass('active');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

here's the repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repQuotes" runat="server" OnItemCommand="repQuotes_ItemCommand"> 
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table id="quotes" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr style="font-weight: bold"><td>Customer</td><td>Company</td><td>Date</td><td>Owner</td><td>Number</td><td>Total</td><%if(User.IsInRole("Admin")){ %><td>Delete</td><%} %></tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>

                <tr>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Id") %>'/>
                    <td><asp:LinkButton ID="QuoteCustomer" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Customer.Contact") %>' CommandName="Choose" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'/></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="QuoteCompany" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Customer.Company") %>' /></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="QuoteDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Date") %>' /></td>
                    <td><asp:LinkButton ID="Owner" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Owner") %>' CommandName="Email" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Owner") %>'/></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="QuoteEmail" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PhoneNumber") %>' /></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="QuoteTotal" runat="server" Text='<%# GetGrandTotalString((QuoteForm.Models.Quote)Container.DataItem) %>' /></td>
                    <%if(User.IsInRole("Admin")){ %>
                    <td><asp:Button ID="Delete" runat="server" Text="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>'/></td>
                    <%} %>
                </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: not hard to find sorting scripts and plugins ... let google be your friend. Question is too broad

Comment: @charlietfl how is it broad? I gave a specific example of the controls I want to use and how I expect it to act? I could make you filter through all of my BS attempts but I don't know if I'd consider that useful information. 

I've been googling, and I haven't found anything that really answered my question. Post here, continue to google, see which one provides an answer first, is that not an acceptable approach?

Comment: Questions here should be specific and code related. Finding code resources or asking for direction on finding them is not part of what SO is all about and it is detailed in the help center. Not trying to be rude...that's just how it works here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you could achieve this.

In your code behind (or server script) add a function that will return a string. The string will represent a class.

```
public string QuoteClass(string user)
{
    return (user == User.Name) ? "myquote" : "otherquote";
}
```

Then include that class in your repeater, at the row level.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr class="<%# QuoteClass(Eval("Owner").ToString()) %>">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Id") %>'/>
    ...
</ItemTemplate>
```

And finally, in your jQuery, you can show and hide these row classes ('myquote' and 'otherquote').

```
    $('input[type=submit]#myQuotes').click(function () {
        if (!$('#myQuotes').hasClass('active'))
        {
            //filter Repeater based on Owner Column
            $('#myQuotes').toggleClass('active');
            $('#allQuotes').toggleClass('active');

            $('.otherquote').hide();
        }
    });
    $('input[type=submit]#allQuotes').click(function () {
        if (!$('#allQuotes').hasClass('active')) {
            $('#allQuotes').toggleClass('active');
            $('#myQuotes').toggleClass('active');

            $('.otherquote').show();
        }
    });
```